# R: How to select the first element of one vector inside a list

Tags: r

I would like to replace the first element of my list (a vector) for the first value of that vector. So if we have:

```
x <- (2, 4, 6)
list <- list(r1 = x, r2 = pi, r3 = month.name)
```

How could I replace the element r1 in my list, with the first element of r1 (2)?
I would like an outcome like this:

```
list
$r1
[1] 2
$r2
[1] 3.141593
$r3
[1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June"     
[7] "July"      "August"    "September" "October"   "November"  "December"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the list element and assign back after subsetting

```
list$r1 <- list$r1[1]
```

-output

```
list
#$r1
#[1] 2

#$r2
#[1] 3.141593

#$r3
#[1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June"      "July"      "August"    "September" "October"   "November" 
#[12] "December"
```

Comment: Typo: it's the first element, `list$r1[1]`.

Comment: Thanks! It was simple but I was blocked.